# Can you preemptively provide password input to a python program?

Tags: python, passwords

I am running python on a linux machine and have a simple program that will prompt the user for input multiple times.

i.e.

```
import getpass


try:
    p1 = getpass.getpass()
except Exception as error:
    print('ERROR', error)

try:
    p2 = getpass.getpass()
except Exception as error:
    print('ERROR', error)
```

Is there a way to pre-provide input to my python program so that it can run all at once?

Something like:

```
# echo "pass1 pass2" > python myprog
# echo "pass1 pass2" | python myprog
```

Of course, neither of these examples work, but just to illustrate what I would like to try to do.

Comment: `getpass()` reads from the terminal, not standard input, unless there's no terminal available.

Comment: You can use Expect to provide input to a program that reads from the terminal. You also need to put each password on a separate line.